# Laravel Localisation messing with Route Resource parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-resource

On my second try I implemented a Multi lingual implementation for a site I am working on by using a `Route::group` that `prefixes` the `{locale}` in the first segment of the url using `routeMiddleware Kernel`.  It works very well except when retrieving route `Resources` with `parameters`.

The implementation has a hiccup in that for some reason it turns the `parameter` into `%2F{id}` (which is not correct) and do not retrieve the resource that my `PublicGalleriesController` requested. I do not understand why, because when I hover over the generated anchor `href` I see the correct url format.  But when I click it give a `404 Not Found` message with the messed up url.

**web.php**  This is my route group that encapsulates all routes with a function

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'middleware' => 'setlocale',
], function() {

   // all my routes are within this route group including:
   Route::resource('gallery', 'PublicGalleriesController');

   Auth::routes();

   Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

       ...

   });

});
```

**App/Http/Middleware/Localisation.php** Route Middleware that is routed through `Kernel.php`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        \App::setLocale($request->segment(1));
        return $next($request);
    }
```

**PublicGalleriesController.php**  Retrieves image paths from model and returns it to client view

```
    public function show($id)
    {
        // Show gallery group images for given group id
        $pics = null;
        $path = null;
        $path = GalleryGroup::find($id);
        
        $pics = Gallery::select('imagefilename', 'group_id')->where('group_id', $id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get()->toArray();

        return view('gallery.show', compact('pics', 'path'));
    }
```

When I hover over a gallery group photo link that is visible on the `index.blade` it shows in the browser left corner as: `localhost/en/gallery/41`.  The `index.blade` retrieves the gallery group primary keys and builds html anchor links in a loop: `<a href="{{ url(app()->getLocale(), 'gallery/' . $item['id']) }}">{{$item['descrp']}}</a>`

When I click this link it should via the `PublicGalleriesController` run the `show` function and retrieve all those gallery group photos but instead returns a `404 Not Found` with the url in the browser showing `localhost/en/gallery%2F41`.  The `%2F` I believe is a Url encoded forward slash.

`php artisan route:list` shows the `show` resource as follows:

```
| Domain | Method    | URI                         | Name         | Action   
         | Middleware                              |
+--------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------
|        | GET|HEAD  | {locale}/gallery/{gallery}  | gallery.show | App\Http\Controllers\PublicGalleriesController@show   
         | web,setlocale                           |
```

Can someone please help me to understand why the url is becoming so messy?

**Laravel version: 5.6.39**

Comment: side note, you should always include what version of Laravel you are using when posting a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for the `url` helper is:

```
function url($path = null, $parameters = [], $secure = null)
```

`$parameters` is an array of parameters, not a path, so it is encoding the `/` that you are using, since parameters are a segment of the URL not a path.

You can adjust the call to `url` to have a more full path or use the `parameters` array as the additional segments, not paths:

```
url(app()->getLocale() .'/gallery/'. $item['id']); // 1 argument
url(app()->getLocale() .'/gallery', [$item['id']]); // 2 arguments
url(app()->getLocale(), ['gallery', $item['id']]);  // 2 arguments
```

You can also use the `route` helper:

```
route('gallery.show', ['locale' => app()->getLocale(), 'gallery' => $item['id']]);
```

If you don't want to have to pass `locale` in for all the URLs you want to generate with the `route` helper you can adjust your middleware to set a default for this parameter:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    App::setLocale($locale = $request->route('locale'));

    URL::defaults(['locale' => $locale]); // set default

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now you don't have to pass that parameter:

```
route('gallery.show', ['gallery' => ...]);
```

If you wanted to not have the `locale` parameter passed to all your route "actions" (Controller methods and closures) that can be done as well. You can add a line like so to that middleware before you return the response:

```
$request->route()->forgetParameter('locale');
```

Comment: Lot of methods to try. Thanks.   I added the parameters as you said and the url looks correct, but I still get the following error:  `Missing required parameters for [Route: gallery.show] [URI: {locale}/gallery/{gallery}]. `

Comment: @Hmerman6006 what is your `route` call that is causing that?

Comment: Sorry was debugging and found two things.  My route call is `route('gallery.show', ['locale' => app()->getLocale(), 'gallery' => $item['id']])`.   It is in the `View: /var/www/html/orob-website/resources/views/inc/nav.blade.php` path, which is my nav bar that is included that is causing the error.  I am trying to figure out which generated route is not correctly containing the necessary parameters.

Comment: @Hmerman6006 make sure `app()->getLocale()` and `$item['id']` have the values you expect

Comment: The second thing I noticed is that the `public function show($id)` in my `PublicGalleriesController` function is not returning the correct `{gallery}` id.  But is for some reason sending the `locale`.  Therefore no images array is returned.

Comment: that is why i gave you the example of adjusting the middleware to remove the `locale` parameter, so it wont pass it to your controller actions (last line of the answer) ... since you have 2 route parameters by default it will pass 2 parameters to your controller and the first is `locale`, so you are getting the `locale` value as the first parameter .... you should probably get into the habit of naming your parameters in your methods to match the route parameter as well

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  Your advice is sound and clear. I now get why you posted the adjustment to the middleware.  I will try them while debugging and will post feedback.  I think I can get through them by this evening GMT time.  To answer your earlier question:  Yes `app()->getLocale()` and `$item['id']` have the values I expect

Comment: I have implemented `$request->route()->forgetParameter('locale');` and the image array is returned. The error `Missing required parameters for [Route: gallery.show]` is caused by the html anchor routes I use to set the `locale`, that is the site has in the navbar links: `<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), 'en') }}">EN</a>`.  Do you know why this `route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), 'en')` will cause an error sometimes but not always?

Comment: you should be using an associative array for the parameters when calling `route(..., ['locale' => ...])` but if you are trying to generate a route to the `gallery.show` route you are missing the 'gallery' parameter, since you don't know what route you are generating that URL for (the current one is dynamic) you can't hard code parameters that you don't know about ... you will have to do it differently, probably by getting the parameters from the current route, merging in the locale change and using that as the parameter for the `route` method ... but this is outside the scope of your question

Comment: You are right again! Magnificent.  It makes things a bit tricky because not all routes has the same named parameter or number of parameters to make one global route generator.  Also the `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName()` does not return parameters only `gallery.show`.  But I will figure this out.  You were alot of help.  Thank you for the time you took to give very good solutions.

Comment: `Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameters()`  a lil hint for you `;-)` ... and perhaps you want to make your own helper to call `route` for you and do this merging with those parameters ... if you have trouble I can add something to this answer for you ... the Router and the URLGenerator are both 'macroable', you can add your own methods to them at run time, another potential option if you don't want to make a global helper function

Comment: sorry ... the method is `parameters` not `getParameters`